# how to make a page with a lot of images? (android, eclipse)

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I want to make a layout that contains a lot of image button but when it contain more than 7 images the app crashes and stops working, so I wanted to know how to make a layout with a lot of image buttons.

I already tried to raise the min sdk version from 8 to 11 but nothing changed

Comment: What size are the images?

Comment: 200x200 thats the largest one of them and the smallest is 100x100

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My wild guess is that your app is running out of memory (OutOfMemoryError is thrown) http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/OutOfMemoryError.html

Simply put, there is not enough RAM allocated to your app to show that many images at once.

I would recommend you to rescale your images before showing them on screen, e.g. by downsampling them while loading. Check out Android's BitmapFactory for that. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html

Don't forget that your app will probably ANR if you decode a lot of images on the main thread so I would recommend that you apply an asynchronous strategy to loading the images. Use Loaders or AsyncTasks to do that.

Best of luck!

Comment: I am sorry, but I am still a beginner how do i do that?